# How to "take" the first part of a slice borrowed in a function?

Tags: rust

### Background

I'm fairly new to Rust, and I'm trying to write a packet parser. It's in a `#[no_std]` environment with no heap.

The input to the parser is a mutable reference to a slice of bytes (`&mut [u8]`), and the output is a `heapless::Vec` of packet header structs (really each is just a struct with a reference to its slice and some functions to obtain the header fields).

### Problem

I'm struggling to split the initial provided slice into the smaller slices required for the individual packet headers. Borrowing the slice in a function and using `slice.take_mut()` to get the first piece seems to not return permissions for the rest of the slice, so a second call to the function doesn't compile.

I've also tried an implementation using `slice.split_at_mut()` with similar problems.

It doesn't help that I'm struggling to understand lifetimes and how they fit into all of this.

### Example

I've tried to reduce my code to a minimal example, but I might've missed out on some important context in doing so.

```rust
#![feature(slice_take)]

fn main() {
    let mut bytes: [u8; 30] = [
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
        11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
        21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
    ];
    let mut s1 = MyStruct::from_bytes(&mut bytes).unwrap();
    let mut s2 = MyStruct::from_bytes(&mut bytes).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", s1);
    println!("{:?}", s2);
    println!("{:?}", bytes);
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct<'a> {
    data: &'a mut [u8],  // This should be a 10-byte slice.
}

impl<'a> MyStruct<'a> {
    fn from_bytes(mut data: &'a mut [u8]) -> Result<MyStruct<'a>, &'static str> {
        if data.len() < 10 {
            return Err("Need 10 bytes.");
        }
        let struct_data = data.take_mut(..10).unwrap();
        Ok(MyStruct{data: struct_data})
    }
}
```

What I was expecting:

```
MyStruct { data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] }
MyStruct { data: [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20] }
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
```

What actually happens:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `bytes` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src\main.rs:10:39
   |
9  |     let mut s1 = MyStruct::from_bytes(&mut bytes).unwrap();
   |                                       ---------- first mutable borrow occurs here
10 |     let mut s2 = MyStruct::from_bytes(&mut bytes).unwrap();
   |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
11 |     println!("{:?}", s1);
   |                      -- first borrow later used here
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close here, but you've got two problems.

The first is that `from_bytes` needs to take a mutable reference to a mutable slice.  This allows it to set the caller-provided slice to a subregion.

The second is that you are passing in `&mut bytes` instead of a slice -- you need to pass in a mutable reference to a slice so that `from_bytes` can adjust that slice to point to a subregion.

Fixing both of these issues:

```
#![feature(slice_take)]

fn main() {
    let mut bytes: [u8; 30] = [
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
        11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
        21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
    ];
    let mut b = &mut bytes[..];
    let s1 = MyStruct::from_bytes(&mut b).unwrap();
    let s2 = MyStruct::from_bytes(&mut b).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", s1);
    println!("{:?}", s2);
    println!("{:?}", b);
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct<'a> {
    data: &'a mut [u8],  // This should be a 10-byte slice.
}

impl<'a> MyStruct<'a> {
    fn from_bytes(data: &mut &'a mut [u8]) -> Result<MyStruct<'a>, &'static str> {
        if data.len() < 10 {
            return Err("Need 10 bytes.");
        }
        let struct_data = data.take_mut(..10).unwrap();
        Ok(MyStruct{data: struct_data})
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c0465707fc2cb647a81a9e75abf55d7f))

Note that you can make this work on stable Rust by using `split_at_mut` instead.  This requires a bit of gymnastics involving `std::mem::take()` -- in fact, this is exactly how `take_mut` is implemented under the hood!

```
fn main() {
    let mut bytes: [u8; 30] = [
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
        11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
        21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
    ];
    let mut b = &mut bytes[..];
    let s1 = MyStruct::from_bytes(&mut b).unwrap();
    let s2 = MyStruct::from_bytes(&mut b).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", s1);
    println!("{:?}", s2);
    println!("{:?}", b);
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct<'a> {
    data: &'a mut [u8],  // This should be a 10-byte slice.
}

impl<'a> MyStruct<'a> {
    fn from_bytes(data: &mut &'a mut [u8]) -> Result<MyStruct<'a>, &'static str> {
        if data.len() < 10 {
            return Err("Need 10 bytes.");
        }
        let (struct_data, tail) = std::mem::take(data).split_at_mut(10);
        *data = tail;
        Ok(MyStruct{data: struct_data})
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=67c718e04fc5ee4973d6ac69fa19f71d))

Comment: Better than returning the tail is taking `&mut &'a mut [u8]`. It also works better with `take_mut()`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman That would probably _require_ `take_mut()` in fact.

Comment: You can also make that work with `split_at_mut()`, with `mem::take()` then reassign.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Right, I always forget about that technique. Looks like that's even how `take_mut()` is implemented.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I've rewritten my answer to better fit the API OP is looking for.

Comment: I didn't even know that a reference itself could be mutable, along with the data behind it. Coming from a Python background, Rust is a big departure. Using your top example I was able to get my code working, thank you.

Comment: @DeathDonkey387 No problem. Note that the bottom example functions in exactly the same way, but doesn't require you to use nightly Rust with experimental features.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the implications of being in a no_std environment, but maybe it would be useful to encapsulate the disunion logic in another structure.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Parts<'a> {
    parts: Vec<MyStruct<'a>>,
    remain: Option<&'a mut [u8]>,
}

impl<'a> From<&'a mut [u8]> for Parts<'a> {
    fn from(mut value: &'a mut [u8]) -> Self {
        let mut parts = Parts {
            parts: Vec::new(),
            remain: None,
        };
        
        while !(value.len() < 10) {
            let struct_data = MyStruct{
                data: value.take_mut(..10).unwrap(),
            };
            parts.parts.push(struct_data);
        };
        
        if value.len() > 0 {
            parts.remain = value.take_mut(..value.len());
        }

        parts
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d4b3f2466d3eb49af64d880b2cbbfd83)